# Why does a Makefile get injected into my root directory out of nowhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, makefile, gulp

Everytime I run `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`, a random Makefile gets generated in my root directory. Any idea why this is happening? I want to prevent this from happening because I don't use `make` at all.

Currently using:

- React
- Webpack
- Gulp
- Ruby on Rails